# Should user configuration data be stored in registry anymore?

Tags: .net, registry, windows-server-2008, appdata

Our Windows application is failing on a new workstation in a large network.

The app fails during a procedure that accesses the `HKCU` registry sub-tree using these operations:

> RegOpenKeyExA, RegQueryValueExA, RegCreateKeyExA, RegQueryValueExA,
>   RegSetValueExString, RegCloseKey

- Is it likely that a large organisation would restrict these registry operations?
- Should user configuration data now be stored in `%APPDATA%` to avoid these sorts of problems?

Comment: "YES" to which question?

Comment: Yes, to both. Allowing end user's application to write the registry has been,  in my opinion, a bad move from the start by Microsoft. Security concerns, maintenability difficulties and, of course, spectacular crashes  have some or every root here. Writing what you need to preserve for a single user in a well know and delimited file system space seems to be a more reasonable solution albeit not a definitive one (Isolated storage seems to be better but more complex to handle for the developper). As I have said this is my opinion